# Zend Framework Amazon S3. How to create subfolder in a bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, zend-framework

How to create subfolder in a bucket?

`$s3->createBucket` creates only a bucket
if I tried `$s3->create('bucket/subfolder')` it says: bucket name contains invalid characters.

tried this too: `$s3->registerStreamWrapper("s3");`

and `mkdir("s3://bucket/subfolder");`

didn't work either.

P.S: credentials are valid. so don't tell me that I'm passing wrong accesKey etc..

Comment: Fun thing:
this worked:
$s3->putFile("/tmp/localfile.jpg", "bucketname/photos/non-existant-folder/hey.jpg");

and it has created non-existant-folder for me.

partially my issue has been solved. :)

but how can I create empty folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 doesn't have folders beyond the bucket, but objects (files) can have `/`s (forward slashes) in their name, and there are methods to retrieve based on a prefix that allows you to emulate a directory-list. This means though, that you can't create an empty folder.

Comment: But I can do it with S3Fox, why?

Comment: are you sure you haven't created a file with a name ending in / ? ('newfolder/') (it wouldn't mean you couldn't also have a file called 'newfolder/1.jpg'). 

What's the actual use case for wanting an empty folder, anyway?

Comment: by far it is more flexible and usefull to use key model style instead of folders